# Visual Studio Code as combined Workspace editor and general purpose editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code (VSC) as both a general purpose text editor and other times as a programming IDE.

When VSC is used as general purpose editor I often have 6-8 files I need to edit on a regularly basis.

When using VSC as a programming IDE I tend to use workspace features.

I tried to pin "general purpose text files", but when I get into a workspace I seem to loose the pinned files.

Is there a way to ask VSC to try to open "general purpose text files" even if I open it in workspace mode? Or not to loose the pinned files when entering workspace mode?